# .net message queueing

Tags: c#, .net, message-queue, messaging

I have a winforms client application that sends messages to an asp.net web service, I need to be able to queue these messages on the client and then then send them in order, waiting for a response from the webservice before sending the next message.

I did look at some examples of queueing using WCF but they seemed to have the queue on the server and not the client.

Any advice abotu what technology to use and on how to implement a solution would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Why wait for the response of the server before sending the next message? there is no good reason to do that. Just mark the messages with a sequence number and process them in order at the server.

MSMQ has a queue both on the client and the server and moves the message when a connection is available.

Comment: The messages must be recived in order.

Comment: Why is that needed? A sequence number will help you to specify in what order the messages should be processed.

Comment: The network/hardware is unreliable and sometimes messages go missing due to faulty network cards and other problems. I need the server to confirm the message got there or i need the client to send it again after a time out period with out a response.

Comment: Then use MSMQ as I said. That will take care of messages getting lost. You can also configure a queue on the client to get received messages from the server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's also good ol' [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but that queues things on the server as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use middleware for the queue (MSMQ etc).

An alternative would be a thread-safe producer/consumer queue at the client. Your "main" code just adds to the queue (ConcurrentQueue in 4.0 might work nicely here, although even in 4.0 I tend to use a utility queue I wrote a while ago instead); and you have a dedicated worker thread that dequeues messages, does the WCF work, and processes the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you need reliable delivery, why not use AMQP with a message broker like RabbitMQ?